# Add different class to all radio buttons previous to the checked one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I am trying to add different class to each radio button previous to the checked one. that said, say if I click on button No3 button No1 should get tclass1 and button No2 should get tclass2...and so on if other button is selected.

here is a sample code

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="1">
            <label for="radio1">one</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="2">
            <label for="radio2">two</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="3">
            <label for="radio3">three</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="4">
            <label for="radio4">four</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="5">
            <label for="radio5">five</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

here is the script I use

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){

    //I use these two lines to clear the last class if exists on each radio button before adding scpecific ones but it does not work
    var lastClass = $(this).closest("ul").find("li label").attr('class').split(' ').pop();
        $(this).closest("ul").find("li label[class*=tclass]").removeClass(lastClass);

        //here I add specific classs to each radio
        $(this).closest("li").prevAll("li").each(function(i) {
            i++;
            $(this).find("label").addClass("tclass" + i);
        });
    });  
});
```

here is the demo
[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8jct6tfs/12/)

as far as I can see the problem is with deleting classes. any help would be much appreciated :(

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the struggle is with adding and removing *dynamic class names* on a set of elements.

I'd suggest to use the same method when determining the relevant class name for an element, whether you want to remove or add it.

Check out this approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  // Takes a selection index, an element, and the element's index
  // Removes or adds a classname to the element's label based on 
  // comparing its own index to the selection's index.
  var modifyClass = function(selectedIndex, element, index) {
    var needsClass = index < selectedIndex;
    $(element)
      .next("label")
      .toggleClass("tclass" + (index + 1), needsClass);
  }

  $("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
    var radioBtns = $("input[type=radio]");
    var checked = radioBtns.index(this);
    var btnArray = radioBtns.toArray();

    // For each radio button, check if it needs a class (index < selected index)
    // and add or remove the right class name
    btnArray.forEach(modifyClass.bind(null, checked));
  })
});
```

```css
form {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
form ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
  position: relative
}
input {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -15px;
  background-color: green;
}
input[type=radio] + label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -15px;
  background-color: gray;
}
label {
  padding-top: 55px;
}
/*this class should be added*/

input[type=radio] + label.tclass1::before {
  background-color: yellow;
}
input[type=radio] + label.tclass2::before {
  background-color: orange;
}
input[type=radio] + label.tclass3::before {
  background-color: red;
}
input[type=radio] + label.tclass4::before {
  background-color: blue;
}
input[type=radio] + label.tclass5::before {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="1">
      <label class="test" for="radio1">one</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="2">
      <label class="test" for="radio2">two</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="3">
      <label class="test" for="radio3">three</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="4">
      <label class="test" for="radio4">four</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="5">
      <label class="test" for="radio5">five</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh cool, i had no idea that you could save a collection of elements like that and access the index from that,

Comment: would this work when multiple radio button groups are on the page ?

Comment: No, you'll have to change the radioBtns selector to only match the clicked group, like you did in your code. I simplified it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this,

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
        var counter = 0;
        var found = false;
        $("input[type=radio]").each(function()
        {
          counter++;
          if(found)
          {
            $(this).next("label").removeClass("tclass"+counter);
          }
          else
          {
            $(this).next("label").toggleClass("tclass"+counter,true);
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
              found = true;
            }
      }
    });
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8jct6tfs/14/

I think this is what you want. let me know if something isn't working or isnt what you meant.

Comment: it works partially as checked element should remain green and this way it's overridden. will see why it;s happening